# Passing a variable from deployment to production environment

Tags: oracle-adf

I was trying to pass a variable dynamically from dev to production using Bindings but no luck.. May be trying it wrong ..
Any suggestions how can I get through this much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate app instances? If so the binding context is not shared.
You can pass a variable on the URL when you call one app from the other.
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/passing_parameters_to_an_adf_p

Comment: Thanks Shay much appreciated